# Perl print line over Prompt

Tags: perl, tui

My script asks for download URLs and sends them to the download queue. The progress of the download should be printed back.

I don't find a way to keep the prompt on bottom and do the status over it.
I tried a search on CPAN, but I found no module for it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.14.0;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::UI;
use Term::ReadLine;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

sub rndStr{ join'', @_[ map{ rand @_ } 1 .. shift ] }

my $q = Thread::Queue->new(); # A new empty queue
my $thr = threads->create(
  sub {
    while (defined(my $item = $q->dequeue())) {
      say "Downloading: ".$item;
      sleep 1;
      #$q->enqueue(1..10) if $item eq '10';
      $q->enqueue(rndStr rand (15)+5, 'a'..'z', 0..9);
    }
  }
);

$q->enqueue(rndStr 10, 'a'..'z', 0..9);
my $url;
my $term = Term::ReadLine->new('brand');
while ($url ne 'end'){
  $url = $term->get_reply( 
      prompt => 'URL to download',
      default => 'end' );
  $q->enqueue($url);
}
say "Finishing remaining downloads";
$q->enqueue(undef);
$thr->join();
```

Comment: You are likely looking for a “Curses” module – https://metacpan.org/search?q=Curses

Comment: I'm on a Windows machine it seams the "Curses" don't work with Win ([Bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=47785)). I can't get it installed on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic just of what you are trying to do is use ANSI codes to move the cursor around.  Something such as ncurses ([windows version](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm)) will allow you do this.

Alternatively you can do it yourself with raw ASCII/ANSI codes (as explained by these two links)

- http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php
- http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html

Or lastly you could use a Perl Module [Win32::Console::ANSI](http://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Console::ANSI) which is designed to help you do this.

As this is a perl question I would suggest looking at Win32::Console::ANSI.

Comment: As I said in the comment by my question, Curses don't work on Windows.

Comment: Well ANSI/ASCII sure does in windows!

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~jlmorel/Win32-Console-ANSI-1.08/lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.pm

Answer (score 2):

`say` adds a newline in the output; use `print` instead. Add a carriage return to write over previous output:

`print "Downloading: ".$item."\r";`